# How to get data from hookproc function winapi (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I have a program that sets a hook on another window. **I want this program to know if my hook function received a message.** How can I do it?

I've had an idea to send message from hook function to my main window, but I don't know how to pass the HWND handler. Also I don't want to use `EnumWindows` or `FindWindow` to find my main window.

Comment: How can I use shared memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to store your target `HWND` in shared memory that both the main program and the hook can access.

If your compiler supports [`#pragma data_seg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/data-seg?view=msvc-170) (ie, MSVC), you can use that to declare an `HWND` variable in a `shared` code section in a DLL. Have your main program and your hook use the same DLL. See [Process shared variable #pragma data_seg usage](https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/process-shared-variable-pragma-data_seg-usage_8_8_30147916.html).

Otherwise, you can use [`CreateFileMapping()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga)+[`MapViewOfFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile) to allocate a block of memory at runtime, and then store/read the `HWND` value from it.  See [Creating Named Shared Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory).

Either way, the main program can then assign the shared `hwnd`, and the hook can read it.